# How to print Date Picker Int month into String Month ? e.g., 12- June-2015

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am very new and want to convert int month to String means 12-06-2015 to 12-June-2015 from Android DatePicker. Please help me how to improve my code whatever i made.. I am very new in Android.Thank you all of you in advance

```
iCal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 


            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
            String month_name = month_date.format(c.getTime());

            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            final int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(c.getTimeInMillis());

            DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(CreateWardRobe.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
                            String month_name = month_date.format(c.getTime());
                            String result ="";
                            String birth = "";
                            birth = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                            birth += "." + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                            birth += "." + year;



                            ((TextView) iDoB).setText(birth);
                            new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(result);

                        }

                    }, year, month, day);
            dp.setIcon(R.drawable.birthday);
            dp.setTitle("Birthday..");
            dp.setMessage("Please Select Baby B'day");

            dp.show();





        }

    });
```

Comment: Post only relevant code. Not everything.

Comment: For better understanding purpose i posted here... did u understand sir my problem ?

Comment: Your problem is with date format. it doesn't matter to me how you generated your date. All this extra code doesn't need to be there.

And I am pretty sure one of these 356 results cover your needs - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+date+format+conversion

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Put it in onDateSet method

```
    import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
     monthString = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];     
     birth = date+"-"+dayOfMonth+"-"+year;
```

Set the value of birth to the textview

Comment: thnxx Fahim .. where should i put these lines in my code ?

Comment: First line - It's an `import`, where do you usually place `import`?  Second line - place it wherever you want to print it out! Come on

Comment: String month_name = month_date.format(c.getTime());
                                String result ="";
                                String birth = "";
                                birth = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                               // birth += "." + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                                birth += "." + year;
                                birth = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1];


                                ((TextView) iDoB).setText(birth);

Comment: @preeti do it as I mentioned in the answer hope it will help

Comment: thank you so much fahim ... now  i am getting String month but when i select another date.. only date and year changes... month is still constant...  :O

Comment: @PreetiSrivastava are you doing it in onDateSet()?

Comment: yes sir... I already done what you had mentioned... still only Date and year is changing  when i choose  date from Datepicker... rest month is still constant.. but one good news for you is that it is displaying in String format